# how to speed up multiprocessed python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-imaging-library, mandelbrot

I'm trying to generate a Mandelbrot Set image, but the image takes ages. The code is annoyingly slow, so If you can help me speed it up, that would be very helpful. thanks. Note that code compiles and runs from my IDE.  I am new to multiprocessing, so please dumb it down a bit for me.

```
def daemon_summoner(r):
'''allows code to be restarted with different file if crash during super high res generation'''
t = Thread(target=process_job(r))
t.start()


def process_job(r):
    """creates a slice of the set"""
    img = Image.new('1', size, color)  # B&W image
    print(int(r + 2*resolution100+1), 'of', int(resolution100 *3))
    r = r * 100
    for rval in range(100):
        for i in range(-resolution, resolution, 1):
            if abrot(((r + rval) / resolution), (i / resolution * 1j)):
                try:
                    img.putpixel((rval, i + resolution,), 0)
                except:
                    print(r, rval, i + resolution)
img.save(('z_images/' + str(resolution) + '/' + str(int(r/100)+int(resolution*.02)) + '.png'))


def abrot(x, y):
    """tests a point"""
    c = (x + y)
    z = 0 + 0j
    for _ in range(5):
        z = z * z + c
    if abs(real(z*z+c))>=2and abs(imag(z*z+c))>=2:
        return False
    for _ in range(int(resolution / 10)):
        if real(z + 0.0001) > float(real(z*z+c)) > real(z - 0.0001):
            return True
        z = z * z + c
        if abs(real(z)) >= 2:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score -1):

The Mandelbrot iteration `z * z + c` can need billions of operations for a single image generation so the first step to speeding it up is to remove the `iterate_once` function and do the job in-line.